# Java string value change in function

Tags: java, string, function, pass-by-reference

I have this very awkward question...

```
void changeString(String str){
    str = "Hello world":
}

main(){
    String myStr = new String("");
    changeString(myStr);
}
```

When `main` returns, the value is still `""` and not `"Hello world"`. Why is that?

Also, how do I make it work? Let's say I want my function `changeString` to change the string it got to "Hello world".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Everyone explained why it doesn't work, but nobody explained how to make it work. Your easiest option is to use:

```
String changeString() {
    return "Hello world";
}

main() {

    String myStr = new String("");
    myStr = changeString();
}
```

Although the method name is a misnomer here. If you were to use your original idea, you'd need something like:

```
void changeString(ChangeableString str) {
    str.changeTo("Hello world");
}

main() {

    ChangeableString myStr = new ChangeableString("");
    changeString(myStr);
}
```

Your `ChangeableString` class could be something like this:

```
class ChangeableString {
    String str;
    
    public ChangeableString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void changeTo(String newStr) {
        str = newStr;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

---

#### A quick lesson on references:

In Java method everything is passed by value. This includes references. This can be illustrated by these two different methods:

```
void doNothing(Thing obj) {
    obj = new Something();
}

void doSomething(Thing obj) {
    obj.changeMe();
}
```

If you call `doNothing(obj)` from `main()` (or anywhere for that matter), `obj` won't be changed in the callee because `doNothing` creates a new `Thing` and assigns that new reference to `obj` *in the scope of the method*.

On the other hand, in `doSomething` you are calling `obj.changeMe()`, and that dereferences `obj` - which was passed by value - and changes it.

Comment: maybe nitpicky, but your second solution won't work because String is a final class (you can't assign a String variable to a ChangeableString).  It would probably help the OP to see how you would have to define ChangeableString.

Comment: @anov "you can't assign a String variable to a ChangeableString" Where am I doing that?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, my func does return a value, so I cant return the new string from it. 
As for the second solution (with the ChangeableString), thats a good one. However, I dont want to mess up my code and add this class for only a single call.
That`s really annoying, if I use Java class thet does not have some "set" function built, do I really have to use this solution of creating another container to pass it? Isnt there some workaround to pass it by &?! Thats really not nice to write a container for each class that does not have a "set" or "change" function....

Comment: @Yura Strings are immutable in Java, AFAIK there's no workaround for that.

Comment: @NullUserException Your original solution had `String myStr = new ChangeableString("");`. Looks good now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NullUserException. I think I found a workaround, I am using a char[] instead of String.

Comment: @Yura I guess the real question we all should have been asking is _why_ you want to change the `myStr` reference.  It might be better to make it a member variable of the class that contains your `main()` method.

Comment: @avon It was copy and pasted, I forgot to change that.

Comment: I'd advise against using a `char[]` if you're just doing it to avoid using the idioms of the language you're coding in.

Comment: @avon my code is far more complicated than the example I wrote. This is a function of another class that is called and it returns the myStr, but not as a return value ( since it already returns another value) but changes it. Just as I would have written in C++:
int foo( &retParam1, &retParam2, &retParam3)

Comment: @Yura It's hard to help without seeing a more representative code sample, but from what your saying it sounds like your code needs to be refactored. Using a `char[]` (or a `String[]` that just contains one `String`!) is just a way to hack around the issue rather than correcting it.  I understand the temptation to fall back on C++ idioms if that's what you're used to, but it's going to impede your progress in learning the new language.

Comment: @avin thank you very much. The char[] works for me and this is a very minor part of the code I dont want to waste any more time refactoring. It just doe not worth it. Thank you a lot thanks to everybody, I got it :))

Answer (score 7):

Java uses a [call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) startegy for evaluating calls.

That is, the value is copied to `str`, so if you assign to `str` that doesn't change the original value.

Answer (score 4):

If the changing of your `String` happens very often you could also assign a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to your variable and change its contents and only convert it to a `String` when this is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on [NullUserException's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486393/java-string-value-change-in-function/3486418#3486418), here's a more general solution:

```
public class Changeable<T> {
   T value;

   public Changeable(T value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return value.toString();
   }

   public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (other instanceof Changeable) {
         return value.equals(((Changeable)other).value);
      } else {
         return value.equals(other);
      }
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      return value.hashCode();
   }
}
```

Yura's original code can then be rewritten as:

```
void changeString(Changeable<String> str){
   str.value = "Hello world":
}

void main() {
   Changeable<String> myStr = new Changeable<String>("");
   changeString(myStr);
}
```

And, just for fun, here it is in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org):

```
class Changeable[T](var self: T) extends Proxy;

object Application {
   def changeString(str: Changeable[String]): Unit = {
      str.self = "Hello world";
   }

   def main(): Unit = {
      val myStr = new Changeable("");
      changeString(myStr);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the reference `myStr` is passed by value to the function `changeString` and the change is not reflected back to the calling function.

P.S : I am not a Java guy.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the phrase "the change is not reflected back" can be misleading. Some changes, depending on the semantics, _ARE_ reflected back. It's definitely not true that pass-by-value means that there are no side effects (and this is also the source of some beginner confusions, e.g. with passing array references and having its elements modifiable by a method).

Answer (score 0):

Bill, I have a solution to your problem which uses a List as a pointer in java!

```
void changeString(List<String> strPointer ){
    String str = "Hello world";
    strPointer.add(0, str);
}

main(){
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    String myStr = new String("");
    changeString(list);
    myStr = list.get(0);
    System.out.println( myStr );
}
```

This answer takes a little extra work to insert and get out the string from the list, however the final line will print "Hello world!"

I hope this can help others as well!

-Port Forward Podcast

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one more solution by `StringBuffer/StringBuilder` worked for me.

```
static void changeValue(StringBuilder str){
    str.append("newValue");
}

main(){
    StringBuilder originalVal= new StringBuilder();
    changeValue(originalVal);
    System.out.println(originalVal.toString());
}
```